# How to set given time zone as default instead of system time zone in Flatpickr?

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, moment-timezone, flatpickr

Flatpickr is using the Date object internally and that always uses the local time of the computer as the default time.

I m using Flatpickr version 4.6.6

Is there any way to set given time zone for flatpickr?

Answer (score 1):

According to their [issue tracker on the matter](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/930), it is not currently possible to set timezone with flatpickr. So you stepped into one of the component's limitations

I suggest you join the people voting for this to be built, or try using another gadget as a replacement.